# Iterating through a JSON file to display multiple polylines

Tags: jquery, google-maps, getjson, google-polyline

I am trying to render a map with multiple polylines that are pulled from an external JSON resource.  Each JSON record has a number of descriptive fields as well as a field containing an array of LatLngs.  The code seems to get the JSON data just fine and to parse it appropriately.  I then iterate through each record mapping a polyline but for some reason I cannot get it to display on the map.  This is my first time using the Google Maps API. I am probably doing something stupid but having trolled through as many examples as I could find, cannot find anything obviously wrong.  All suggestions gratefully received.

The basis for the code for displaying the polylines was taken from the following example: http://code.google.com/intl/no/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polyline-simple.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
     #map_canvas {
        width: 1024px;
        height: 700px;
      }
</style>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

function initialize(){
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(0, 23);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 4,
      center: latlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

    var url = "http://webstore.thedatahub.org/stevesong/afterfibre/testdata2.json?_limit=3";
    var path = [];
        $.getJSON(url, function (data) {

            //  Parse the Linestring field into an array of LatLngs
            $.each(data.data, function(index, record) {
                line = JSON.parse(record.Linestring);

                //  Parse the array of LatLngs into Gmap points
                for(var i=0; i < line.length; i++){
                    path.push(new google.maps.LatLng(line[1],line[0]));
                }
                var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
                  path: path,
                  strokeColor: '#ff0000',
                  strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                  strokeWeight: 3
                });

                polyline.setMap(map);

            });

        });
    }

    // google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
  <div id="map_canvas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Greg Mahlknecht for providing the final piece of the puzzle. In order to have each JSON record display uniquely as opposed to one giant polyline, the polyline array needs to be reinitialised AFTER each ".each" iteration.  Here is the final version that finally does what I was after.  Thanks Mitch and Greg.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
     #map_canvas {
        width: 1024px;
        height: 700px;
      }
</style>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

function initialize(){
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(0, 23);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 4,
      center: latlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

    var url = "http://webstore.thedatahub.org/stevesong/afterfibre/testdata2.json?_limit=5";

        $.getJSON(url, function (data) {

            //  Parse the Linestring field into an array of LatLngs
            $.each(data.data, function(index, record) {
                var mypath = new Array();
                line = JSON.parse(record.Linestring);
                //  Parse the array of LatLngs into Gmap points
                for(var i=0; i < line.length; i++){
                    //Tokenise the coordinates
                    var coords = (new String(line[i])).split(",");
                    mypath.push(new google.maps.LatLng(coords[1], coords[0]));
                }
                var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
                    path: mypath,
                    strokeColor: '#ff0000',
                    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                    strokeWeight: 3
                });
                polyline.setMap(map);
            });

        });
    }

    // google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
  <div id="map_canvas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not tokenising the coorinates when looping through 'lines'

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
     #map_canvas {
        width: 1024px;
        height: 700px;
      }
</style>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"         type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?    sensor=false"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

function initialize(){
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(0, 23);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 4,
      center: latlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

    var url = "http://webstore.thedatahub.org/stevesong/afterfibre/testdata2.json?    _limit=3";
    var mypath = new Array();
        $.getJSON(url, function (data) {

            //  Parse the Linestring field into an array of LatLngs
            $.each(data.data, function(index, record) {
                line = JSON.parse(record.Linestring);
        //  Parse the array of LatLngs into Gmap points
        for(var i=0; i < line.length; i++){
        //Tokenise the coordinates
        var coords = (new String(line[i])).split(",");
                    mypath.push(new google.maps.LatLng(coords[1], coords[0]));
        }
                var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
                  path: mypath,
                  strokeColor: '#ff0000',
                  strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                  strokeWeight: 3
                });

                polyline.setMap(map);

            });

        });
    }

    // google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
  <div id="map_canvas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Mitch!  That worked a treat although it does present another problem in that the polylines are all being joined together into one big polyline i.e. the end of one polyline has a straight line joining it to the beginning of the next one.  Perhaps I can create an array of polylines?

Comment: The polyline is rendered according to the coordinates iterated over in 'path' array.

Comment: Understood, but that would appear to make one giant polyline when what I had intended,was for each JSON record to be displayed as a separate polyline.  Clearly I am missing something basic about how Gmaps works.